# Why an interface argument allows any type

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

I'm trying to inherit base interface IScreen which is going to be extended with IModal, IEmbedded or ITab, and lock down methods so that they are specific to an interface. But what happens is that the method `public OpenModal(modal: IModal)` just accepts any type for some reason.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20Framework%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22use%20strict%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IScreen%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IModal%20extends%20IScreen%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ITab%20extends%20IScreen%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IEmbedded%20extends%20IScreen%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20BaseScreen%20implements%20IScreen%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20HandleCloseEvent()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20DetailsScreen%20extends%20BaseScreen%20implements%20IModal%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ListScreen%20extends%20BaseScreen%20implements%20IEmbedded%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20OpenerService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20OpenScreen(screen%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20OpenModal(modal%3A%20IModal)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Controller%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(openerService%3A%20OpenerService)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20detailsScreen%3A%20DetailsScreen%20%3D%20new%20DetailsScreen()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20listScreen%3A%20ListScreen%20%3D%20new%20ListScreen()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20openerService.OpenModal(212121)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20openerService.OpenModal(listScreen)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

```
namespace Framework {
    "use strict";

    interface IScreen { }
    interface IModal extends IScreen { }
    interface ITab extends IScreen { }
    interface IEmbedded extends IScreen { }

    class BaseScreen implements IScreen {
        public HandleCloseEvent() {

        }
    }

    class DetailsScreen extends BaseScreen implements IModal {

    }

    class ListScreen extends BaseScreen implements IEmbedded {

    }

    class OpenerService {
        public OpenScreen(screen: IScreen) {

        }

        public OpenModal(modal: IModal) {

        }
    }

    class Controller {
        constructor(openerService: OpenerService) {

            var detailsScreen: DetailsScreen = new DetailsScreen();
            var listScreen: ListScreen = new ListScreen();

            openerService.OpenModal(212121); // Expected error
            openerService.OpenModal(listScreen); // Expected error
        }
    }
}
```

- Am I missing some compiler configurations that I am not
  receiving any errors?
- Am I misunderstanding how interfaces work?

Comment: I believe this happens because your interfaces are empty; it should change when you add properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way TypeScript works: with *structural typing* (called also *duck typing*).

You declares:

```
   public OpenModal(modal: IModal) {
   }
```

Because all your interfaces are empty, it is equivalent to write:

```
   public OpenModal(modal: {}) {
   }
```

This signature accepts every object, because all objects are compatible to an empty object. `212121` is an object (in JavaScript a number is an object). `listScreen` is an object too.

You can notice it is useless to declare several interfaces for the empty object type:

```
interface IScreen { }
interface IModal extends IScreen { }
interface ITab extends IScreen { }
interface IEmbedded extends IScreen { }
```

Here, all your interfaces are equivalent. There is no hierarchy. You can do:

```
let a: IScreen
let b: IModal
let c: IModal = a // type '{}' ('IScreen') is compatible to type '{}' ('IModal')
let d = {}
let e: IModal = d // type '{}' is compatible to type '{}' ('IModal')
```

See also:

- *[What is structural typing?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing)*
- [The Handbook on *interfaces*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)
- *[Types are structural](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html#types-are-structural)*

Comment: Thanks, my colleague mentioned that the behavior feels like duck typing and I found the solution right after :D The only problem I have with this, that it is not possible to have interface markers in typeScript